# Why does k-fold in sk learn not print array values

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I'm following the docs for sklearn k-fold validation, and I wrote this code:

```
    import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

X = ["w", "x", "y", "a"]
print(X[0])
kf = KFold(n_splits=4)
for train, test in kf.split(X):
    print(X[(test)])
```

Which outputs an error on the last line:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Why does this error occur? Sorry, obviously I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as the error says. Your error is coming from your print statement. It is because the indexing being generated by `KFold.split` is not compatible with python lists. Try this,

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

X = np.array(["w", "x", "y", "a"])
kf = KFold(n_splits=4)
for train, test in kf.split(X):
    print(train, test)
    print(X[test])
```

Output:

```
[1 2 3] [0]
['w']
[0 2 3] [1]
['x']
[0 1 3] [2]
['y']
[0 1 2] [3]
['a']
```